# No 'Workspaces' section in GNOME Tweaks

Tags: 18.04, workspaces, gnome-tweaks

I do not have any 'Workspaces' option in GNOME Tweaks on Ubuntu 18.04. As said in a lot of places, I have installed `gnome-tweaks` by

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
```

But even there the 'Workspaces' section is absent. Image added to show how the Tweaks GUI looks like.

[image]

I thought there was a problem with my installation of `ubuntu-desktop`. So, I installed it again but to no avail.

Can someone help?

Comment: Are you using Unity Desktop? I won't expect a tool made for GNOME to work for other DE.

Comment: Thanks for the comment...this was one of the the issues

Comment: It's absolutely fine (and very much encouraged) to [add an answer your question](https://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer). But **not** to the question itself. Please post your solution as an answer below by clicking the 'Answer your question' button. You can find the removed solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/1234680/3).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the comments, I was trying to use `unity-control-center` with `gnome-tweaks` tool. Deleting `gnome-control-center` and `gnome-tweaks`, I could not still open `unity-control-desktop` due to segmentation fault. Probably this was the reason, some time back, I tried to switch to `gnome-control-center`. I found another solution at https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2380509, where it is explained that this issue can be sorted out by using

```
setsid unity
```

---

<sub>Source: [added to the question by OP](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/1234680/3)</sub>